# Can Boost Graph Find Connected Components Based on Weight?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, adjacency-list, connected-components

I'm successfully using boost graph's component finder to assign color, i.e. the component's index to every vertex in my graph like so:

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> g;

std::vector<int> compon_map(boost::num_vertices(g));

int number_of_components = boost::connected_components(g, &compon_map[0]);
```

This will then yield a different `number_of_components` after each iteration in my simulation (not shown) because I do

```cpp
boost::clear_vertex(v, g);
```

in between to erase some edges based on some condition.

The thing is that in my simulation I want to write out some property (say weight) of all edges, and the length of the edge iterator needs to stay constant (dataset restrictions).

My question is therefore: Is there a way to *pass some edge property* like a

```cpp
int L = boost::num_edges(g);

std::vector<bool> is_still_existent(L); // or
std::vector<double> edge_weights(L);
```

to the `boost::connected_components` (that then counts edges only based on that property) or is there another way to trick the edge iterator to stay at the initial length even after having removed edges?

Thanks in advance for any hints :)

Comment: I'm confused by your code snippets. That cannot work without external vertex index due to `listS` being used. Can you make your code snippets self-contained/consistent for the scope of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use a filtered graph adaptor with an edge filter. I have several answers [up on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20filtered_graph) showing how to use it, but will see whether I can usefully create an example based on on your snippet.

So I made a self-contained sample¹: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/),

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <random>

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;
using W = double;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    G g;
    auto seed = 9353; // fixed seed for demo
    if (argc > 1) {
        seed = atol(argv[1]);
        std::cerr << "Using PRNG seed: " << seed << "\n";
    }

    std::mt19937 engine(seed);
    auto weight_gen = bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<W>(0, 1), engine);
    boost::generate_random_graph(g, 10, 6, engine);

    std::map<E, W> weights;

    for (auto e : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        weights[e] = weight_gen();
    
    std::vector<int> components(boost::num_vertices(g));
    auto cmap = boost::make_iterator_vertex_map(components.data());


    int n = boost::connected_components(g, cmap);

    std::cerr << n << " components\n";

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, g));
    dp.property("style", boost::make_constant_property<V>(std::string("filled")));
    dp.property("color",
                boost::make_transform_value_property_map(
                    [](int componentid) {
                        static std::array cc{"red",    "green", "yellow",
                                             "blue",   "brown", "black",
                                             "orange", "purple"};
                        return cc[componentid % cc.size()];
                    },
                    cmap));
    dp.property("label", boost::make_assoc_property_map(weights));

    boost::write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g, dp);
}
```

which generates a pseudo-random graph:

[image]

Let's add some filtering to it:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0f7734fe58bade5)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <random>

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;
using W = double;

struct NonRemoved {
    std::set<E> const* _ref;
    bool operator()(E e) const { return not _ref->contains(e); }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    G g;
    auto seed = 9353; // fixed seed for demo
    if (argc > 1) {
        seed = atol(argv[1]);
        std::cerr << "Using PRNG seed: " << seed << "\n";
    }

    std::mt19937 engine(seed);
    auto weight_gen = bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<W>(0, 1), engine);
    boost::generate_random_graph(g, 10, 6, engine);

    std::map<E, W> weights;

    for (auto e : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        weights[e] = weight_gen();
    
    std::vector<int> components(boost::num_vertices(g));
    auto cmap = boost::make_iterator_vertex_map(components.data());

    auto random_edges = [&g] {
        auto [f,l] = edges(g);
        std::deque<E> re(f,l);
        std::random_shuffle(begin(re), end(re));
        return re;
    }();

    std::set<E> removed;
    NonRemoved predicate{&removed};

    boost::filtered_graph<G, NonRemoved, boost::keep_all> f(g, predicate, {});
    do {
        int n = boost::connected_components(f, cmap);
        std::cerr << n << " components\n";

        boost::dynamic_properties dp;
        dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, f));
        dp.property("style", boost::make_constant_property<V>(std::string("filled")));
        dp.property("color",
                    boost::make_transform_value_property_map(
                        [](int componentid) {
                            static std::array cc{"red",    "green", "yellow",
                                                 "blue",   "brown", "black",
                                                 "orange", "purple"};
                            return cc[componentid % cc.size()];
                        },
                        cmap));
        dp.property("color",
                    boost::make_function_property_map<E>([&removed](E e) {
                        return removed.contains(e) ? "red" : "blue";
                    }));
        dp.property("label",
            boost::make_function_property_map<E>([&removed, &weights](E e) {
                if (removed.contains(e))
                    return std::string("REMOVED");
                return std::to_string(weights.at(e));
            }));

        std::ofstream ofs("graph_" + std::to_string(random_edges.size()) + ".dot");
        boost::write_graphviz_dp(ofs, f, dp);

        removed.insert(random_edges.front());
        random_edges.pop_front();
    } while (not random_edges.empty());
}
```

Now writes a series of `graph_XXX.dot` graphs that display as:

[image]

---

¹ (changing the [vertex container selector to `vecS` for simplicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445866/can-boost-graph-find-connected-components-based-on-weight/67447926#comment119215822_67445866))

Comment: Ah, thanks for the early accept. I was just having fun coming up with a selfcontained example.

Comment: Thanks, so much! I found a workaround in the meantime, where I *do* clear the vertices, and stick with removing the edges, but give every edge an ID and then while the number of edges shrinks and the edge iterator does not treat the removed edges any more, I hold a full-sized vector of zeros of length of the number of initial edges in the background, while I iterate over the remaining edges and set the remaining weights in the vector of zeros. That way removed edges count as weight zero, and I don't have to worry about fake removing them, and passing some `is_removed` bool to `boost::conn_com`

Comment: Haha, it's incredible how you always make a full-blown scenario out of some miserably-explained lines of a question :D thanks so much. And yes, I hope you're having fun! Btw. I really have to acknowledge your help in my thesis, I'm finishing my master in physics in Heidelberg. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Added a live demo with filtered-graph progressively removing (random) edges (the frames are [rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjZkn.gif) in reverse order because that's more aesthetically pleasing to me :))